# equivalent of exit /B in shell scripting

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, unix

I am converting one script from .bat file to .sh (Basically moving from windows machine to Unix machine). I have a statement in .bat file "exit /B". what will be the equivalent of this statement in shell script.

Comment: Do you know what `Exit` does in a `.bat` script? and do you know what `Exit` does in a `.sh` script? Have you entered `help exit` in either of their respective consoles? What did it say? and what did you not understand about what it said? What did you try? and what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

In windows using EXIT /B will stop execution of a batch file or subroutine and return control to the command processor or to the calling batch file or code immediately. You Unix there is no such command and you don't even need that.

In windows if you call a function and you do not put `EXIT /B` at the end of the function it will start executing all the codes after the function end. When you use `EXIT /B` the control will return to the line from where you did the function call. So a `EXIT /B` instruct the control like `go back to the location from where you called me` else I will start executing all the codes from here onwards. In other words in DOS/windows `EXIT /B` confirm the end of a function else control will not understand where is the end of the function and continuously execute all the codes.

In Unix there is not such issue so you don't need to have such `EXIT /B` in unix. In shellscript when you call a function once function end control returns back to the point from where you have called the function.